# Why not stream outside cameras into the in flight entertainment system

Tags: commercial-aviation, inflight-entertainment

Why do some carriers choose not to stream external views on planes where GMCS cameras are standard, such as the 777-300 or the Airbus A380?

Comment: I can't find it, but there was a crash that the passengers got a "birds eye view" of while they crashed. I thought it was [American Flight 191](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_191) but I'm not sure. 191 had a "cockpit" camera that showed the pilots to screens in the cabin, so they may have watched the pilots struggle first hand.

Comment: I do not think this contributed to the crash